# 2.3 Android Device Natigation Drawer not geting Method getActionBar

Tags: android

Hello Friends i Implement one demo for Navigation Drawer example my main class file is as below :

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
     // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_websearch:
        // create intent to perform web search for this planet
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
        // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
 */
public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                        "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
      }
   }
}
```

And My Menifest file is  as Below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

This Example in 4.0 Android device Working Fine But In 2.3 Android Device get error message like

```
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity.getActionBar
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:98)
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-26 10:18:32.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1107):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 10):

From the Android documentation:

> The ActionBar APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11) but they are also available in the Support Library for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.

Therefore, you should use [getSupportActionBar()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportActionBar%28%29) if you suport devices below API lvl 11.

Follow the ActionBar tutorial in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) for more information.

Comment: I used Support library and also implement one demo for that refer below link
[Demo Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896049/drawerlayout-not-working-in-2-3-device).

Answer (score 2):

Use getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar().
Also when you are invalidating the menu, use supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() instead of invalidateOptionsMenu().

Answer (score 0):

ActionBar APIs where introduced in HoneyComb so you cannot call them for API < 11.

One way is [ActionBarCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html). Another option is to use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).