# DrawerLayout not working in 2.3 Device

Tags: android

Hello Friends i implement one Demo Applicaiton for DrawerLayout in All Android Device

MainClass as below :

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
     // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_websearch:
        // create intent to perform web search for this planet
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getSupportActionBar().getTitle());
        // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
 */
public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                        "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
      }
    }
  }
```

my drawer_main.xml like below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My menifest.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.appcompactdemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

 </manifest>
```

I used Android Support Library which is feasible in 2.1 or above device as per actionbar document but in my above example it is working on 4.0 device in 2.3 device  it gives me error like as below:

```
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:702)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)  
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  ... 35 more
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x10102fd a=-1}
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:350)
07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:343)
 07-27 08:46:56.037: E/AndroidRuntime(616):     ... 38 more
```

any Idea how can I Solve it ?

Comment: I know it has something to do with the use of `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"` in the drawer_list_item.xml they use as an example. Not sure how to fix it yet... working on it now.

Comment: I have experience similar symptoms with a spinner. It seems like theme is buggy ``@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar``. Setting it to ``@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light`` for ex worked around the problem for me.

Answer (score 9):

The problem lies in the drawer_list_item.xml. You will need to remove these 2 lines:

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
```

Once those are removed it should work. Both of these items need later api versions to work correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Stuck in the same problem from the same tutorial after applying all the suggestions of the other answers, I've found (a few moments ago) that it's the `invalidateOptionsMenu();` too that creates a problem.
You've to use the `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();` and it magically works.

```
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,                  /* host Activity */
        mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
        R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }
    };
```