# mDrawer can't work on android >3

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I builded an app with simply webview and mDrawer slide menu. But after seeing that it's not working on > 3  android i have added a support library and made some changes but it's still not working. 
here is the code

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity   {

     private LayoutInflater mInflater;
     private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
     WebView browser;
     // ListView represents Navigation Drawer
     private ListView mDrawerList;

     // ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the action bar
     private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
     private String mTitle = "";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        browser.loadUrl("");
         browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
         WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

        // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                        R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                        R.string.drawer_close) {

                /** Called when drawer is closed */
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

                        invalidateOptionsMenu();

                }

                /** Called when a drawer is opened */
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Menu");

                        invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }


        };
        browser.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
        {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                    switch(keyCode)
                    {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                            if(webView.canGoBack())
                            {
                                webView.goBack();
                                return true;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
                        R.layout.drawer_list_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menus));

        // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Enabling Home button
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // Enabling Up navigation
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

                        // Getting an array of rivers
                        String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menus);

                        // Currently selected river
                        mTitle = menuItems[position];

                        // Creating a fragment object


                        // Passing selected item information to fragment
                        Bundle data = new Bundle();
                        data.putInt("position", position);
                        data.putString("url", getUrl(position));



                        // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                        fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                                if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0)    
                                     finish();                                                               
                            }
                        });

                        // Creating a fragment transaction
                        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                        // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction


                        // Committing the transaction
                        ft.commit();

                        // Closing the drawer
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

                }
        });     




}
```

I have tried to change getActionBar() to getSupportActionBar() but i got  next error: 
The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type new ActionBarDrawerToggle(){}

Logcat:

04-03 14:39:29.237: E/AndroidRuntime(687): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-03 14:39:29.237: E/AndroidRuntime(687): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.com/com.example.com.MainActivity}:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.com.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.com-2.apk]

Manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.com"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.com.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

  </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not added these two functions in your code, then add it and try. It will work.

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
     // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Change the minSdkVersion=11, and on what version of android are you testing this??

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question well. I am trying make app works on mindsk 8 not just to change it.

Comment: Sorry, My bad. This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896049/drawerlayout-not-working-in-2-3-device